# Review Close Votes without a single vote

Tags: support, vote-to-close, review-page

I was just prompted to [review a Close Vote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/close) for a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83611/5764) that had no previous votes to close:

[image]

Usually, a close vote tally will be added after each reason selected (could be more than one). As such, and since I did not initiate the close vote, I thought there would be at least one such a tally, although there was none. This is what I expected it to look like:

[image]

This is not specific to closing as TL; here's on for NARQ:

[image]

How does this happen? How do these questions end up on the list of posts to review?

Comment: Mmmm, I guess it is a glitch of some sort. Close votes expire after a while to avoid that a question is closed because it accumulated close votes over a long time frame. So it could be possible that this is not properly handled by the review system yet. Another possibility might be some sort of sync error with the DB.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: In this instance, the [Close Vote review history](http://tex.stackexchange.com/review/close/20371) for the question might give some hint of what's going on: I think what happened was that (1) Someone voted to close; (2) Someone voted to leave open; (3) I voted to close; (4) Subsequent user(s) voted to close. (1) is never visible in the review (since it's not a review); (2) "overruled" (1), dropping the count to 0 (or removing it) and then I came into the picture. "Leave open" votes "overrule" "close votes" using a FIFO approach. Hmmmm.

Comment: I would assume it got there because it was assigned a very low quality score by the system, mostly because of its brevity, but I think there are other (undisclosed) grounds for scoring. Some of these posts also get flagged by the system and can be found on the flag list.

Comment: @doncherry: With the reason "Close as TL?" I don't recall seeing that. Usually these tend to be for low quality, vandalism, duplicates (and others) - all of which are measurable categories. I can't see how such a measure would hold for TL.

Comment: @Werner That’s the flags, yes. I could just imagine that the system also uses these quality scores to suggest closing as TL.